# How to mock export default function

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

```
//MyConfig.ts
export default function getConfig(name: string): string {
  // do some logic
  return var;
}
```

```
//MyUtil.ts
import getConfig from './MyConfig';

export default class MyUtil {
  public static isFoo(): boolean {
    const config = getConfig();
    return config == 'Foo';
  }
}
```

```
//MyUtil.test.ts
import MyUtil from '../MyUtil';
import * as config from '../MyConfig';

const configMock = config.default as jest.Mock;

describe('tests', () => {
  it('blah', async () => {
    configMock.mockReturnValue('mock-config');
    const foo = MyUtil.isFoo();
  });
});
```

I tried to mock getConfg function from MyConfig.ts in MyUtil.test.ts. I am getting an error 'configMock.mockReturnValue is not a function'.

How do I mock the export default function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direct function and assign the value in the spec file.
Like

```
configMock = () => return 'mockConfig';
```

you don't need to use mockReturnValue for that case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `jest.mock('../MyConfig')` in your test code.

See the jest documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules

```js
//MyUtil.test.ts
import MyUtil from '../MyUtil';
import * as config from '../MyConfig';

jest.mock('../MyConfig')

describe('tests', () => {
  it('blah', async () => {
    config.default.mockReturnValue('mock-config');
    const foo = MyUtil.isFoo();
  });
});
```